# how to loop through directories and cd to each directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

So, how do I loop through each directory and actually cd to that directory on each loop?  I need to actually cd because I need to execute a exe in each one, however if I don't execute the exe while in the directory, the application doesn't run correctly (it loads dependencies based on current folder)

so this doesn't work

```
for /r %%i in (*.exe) do start "" /b "%%i"
```

I need to loop through each directory, cd to that directory, then execute

```
for %%i in (*.exe) do start "" /b "%%i"
```

How do I loop through each directory and cd to that directory?

Comment: You may just be able to use the same structure and use the /D option.  See `start /?`.

Comment: Type `start /?` into a command prompt window and learn about the `/D` option...

Answer (score 1):

```
for /r %%i in (*.exe) do PUSHD "%%~dpi"&start "" /b "%%~nxi"&POPD
```

see `for /?` from the prompt for documentation on selecting parts of a pathname.

Answer (score 0):

I have some old legacy applications that behave like you describe and the easiest way to solve that is to use the `START` command with the `/D` option.  It has always worked for me.

```
for /r %%i in (*.exe) do start "" /b  /D "%%~dpi" "%%~nxi"
```